# How can I ensure certain hadoop jobs dont end up running in the same datanode when using Fair Scheduler?

Tags: hadoop, scheduling, nutch

When using the nutch crawler, the fetch jobs are created such that URLs from same host end up in a single data node to maintain crawl politeness(1 QPS). However, certain hosts allow more than 1 QPS and so the URLs are partitioned accordingly. For such hosts, the URLs will be in two fetch jobs meant to be run on two different data nodes. But sometimes Fair scheduler schedules those jobs(reduce tasks) to the same data node.

So is there any way to work around this issue?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to do something like this because it will impact the rest of your Hadoop cluster...

You can set the number of reduce slots per node to 1. The configuration parameter you want to change for this is `mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But we have to have a minimum of 3 reduce slots. Can I modify some part of fair scheduler to do this? Any ideas?